# How can I allow incoming connections to a server inside of VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I have a NAT configured to run when loading up my favorite Linux distribution in VitualBox. This allows outgoing connections to work successfully.

How do I allow incoming connections to this box, like, say, Web traffic? The IP address is 10.0.2.15. A ping request from my main box results in a Timeout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VirtualBox (after version 1.3.8, anyway) will let you map incoming connections in the NAT configuration. There's an excellent tutorial on [Aviran's Place](https://web.archive.org/web/20110116105152/http://www.aviransplace.com/2008/06/12/virtualbox-configuring-port-forwarding-with-nat/) that describes the steps to configure port mapping.