# How to access webmin (and httpd) inside virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

I have a Centos inside a virtual box.
I gave it 2 network connections. One is set to NAT, the other is set to Host-only.

I can ping from inside virtual box to host. Also can ping from host to the Centos inside the virtual box.

I have installed webmin and https in the Centos.
I can open the webmin and a php script from inside the virtual box.
But I can't open both of them from the host.

Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135/how-can-i-allow-incoming-connections-to-a-server-inside-of-virtualbox?rq=1 might help you

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem simply by telling the firewall to allow the ports (10000 and 80).